# "This theme can't be applied to the desktop."

Tags: windows, windows-8, themes

[image]

In Windows 8.1, I am getting this popping up completely randomly. I don't use themes. I even have the service disabled. I've tried enabling and disabling the Themes service, but that didn't fix it. This comes up at completely random times and I cannot diagnose what is causing it.

How can I silence this without enabling some ugly theme on my desktop?

Comment: Does this happen when you actually do use a theme?

Comment: The process name is: `SettingSyncHost.exe`

Answer (score 2):

I believe this has to do with a corrupted "Synced Theme" somehow. You start Windows, it tries to sync the theme and can't for some reason (possibly a missing image file?), then displays the error.

This is mostly speculation.

Try creating a new theme and see if that solves the problem. Ultimately this is what solved the problem for me.